# If $p^2-n^2$ is divisible $12$, where $p$ is prime, does that mean that $n$ is a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Except for 2 and 3.

If you square a prime, subtract from it the square of another prime, and divide it by 12, the result is always integer, right?

Would this work for testing whether a possible prime with n digits is indeed prime?

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: How about trying $115^2-5^2$?

Comment: How would it help? If $m$ and $n$ are any two numbers that differ by a multiple of 6, then $m^2 - n^2$ is a multiple of 12.

Comment: $\dfrac{25^2-5^5}{12}=50$ is an integer but $25$ is not prime

Answer (score 12):

Suppose $n$ is an integer that is divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$.  Then $$n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$$ is divisible by $12$: since $n$ is odd, both factors are even, and since $n$ is not divisible by $3$, one of the factors is divisible by $3$.  (There are many other easy ways to verify this as well, for instance using modular arithmetic.)  It follows that if you have two such integers $n$ and $m$, then $$n^2-m^2=(n^2-1)-(m^2-1)$$ is also divisible by $12$.

So, your statement works not just primes other than $2$ and $3$, but for *all* integers that are divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$.

Comment: It is only a small step to change the $12$ to $24$

Comment: Sure, but 12 is what is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Consider numbers of the form $6k\pm 1$. All primes greater than $3$ are of that form, but not all numbers of that form are primes. For $m>n$ compute
$$(6m\pm 1)^2-(6n\pm 1)^2=(36m^2\pm 12m +1)-(36n^2\pm 12n +1)\\ =36(m^2-n^2)\pm 12(m\pm n)$$
That difference is plainly divisible by $12$, whether or not neither, one, or both of $(6m\pm 1)$ and $(6n\pm 1)$ are primes.

So the test does not comment on the primeness of a number.